# Issues transforming tuple to denormalized dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, tuples

I have a tuple which is a list of 200 dicts:

eg:

```
mytuple= ([{'reviewId': '1234', 'userName': 'XXX', 'userImage': 'imagelink', 'content': 'AAA', 'score': 1, 'thumbsUpCount': 1, 'reviewCreatedVersion': '3.31.0', 'at': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 1, 11, 49, 34), 'replyContent': "replycontent", 'repliedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 1, 12, 19, 51)}, 
           {'reviewId': '5678', 'userName': 'S L', 'userImage': 'imagelink2', 'content': "content2", 'score': 1, 'thumbsUpCount': 0, 'reviewCreatedVersion': '3.31.0', 'at': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 29, 12, 27, 46), 'replyContent': "replycontent2", 'repliedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 29, 12, 30, 40)}])
```

Ideally, I'd like to transform this into a dataframe with the following column headers:

| reviewId | userName | userImage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | XXXX | imagelink |
| 5678 | S L | imagelink2 |

and so on with the column headers as the key and the columns containing the values.

mytuple was initially of size 2, from which I removed the second index and brought it down to just a list of dicts.

I tried different possibilities which include:
`df=pd.DataFrame(mytuple)`
`df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mytuple)`
`df=pd.json_normalize(mytuple)`

However, in all these cases, I get a dataframe as below

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {'reviewId':..} | {'reviewId':..} | {} | {} |

I'd like to understand where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you provided the sample dictionaries correctly? because according to your example in the question, json_normalize works well.

Comment: As mentioned by Bushmaster, all three methods `pd.DataFrame(mytuple)`, `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mytuple)` and `pd.json_normalize(mytuple)`, will correctly provide you with all the information and print your requested output with `print(df[['reviewId', 'userName', 'userImage']])`. Please verify your question.